# Drupal 8 Google Analytics module, get the ID programatically

Tags: drupal, google-analytics, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I'm trying to get the Google Analytics ID (UA-xxxxxxx-yy), which is set in /admin/config/system/google-analytics . Is it possible to get it as a variable in a controller or a form, maybe using a service?

Comment: Welcome. The GA module doesn't have a service so you'd need to use config, as shown by EricLavault here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the schema defined in `google_analytics.schema.yml` we can read :

```yml
google_analytics.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'Google Analytics settings'
  mapping:
    account:
      type: string
      label: 'Web Property ID'
      ...
```

So the Google Analytics ID is stored in config and can be retrieved like this :

```
$config = \Drupal::config('google_analytics.settings');
$id = $config->get('account');
```